# React: how to add css transition into inline style

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I would like to have a button, after clicked, state isBackward become true and the inline-style would be added into the div container and have animation.

I have tried below code in React, only transition doesn't work, other properties work.
Anyone got the idea to have the transition for the marginLeft to have animation?

```
const slideStyle = {
    width: 400 + "%",
    marginLeft: dis + "px",
    transition: "marginLeft 1s"
  };

 <div style={isBackward ? slideStyle : null} className="quote-box-wrap">
     {quotes.map((item, index) => (
          <Quote
            key={index}
            id={index}
            content={item.sentence}
            author={item.author}
          />
     ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must write as follows:

```
  const slideStyle = {
    width: 400 + "%",
    marginLeft: dis + "px",
    transition: "margin-left 1s"
  };
```